# como puedo capturar el valor de un input q se duplica con su mismo id desde javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

tengo este problema y ya he logrado capturar dos textos q vienen desde php, pero no he podido capturar el valor del input el cual debo llenar con caracteres numericos y mostrarlos en un modal emergente q permite verficiar la informacion ingresada en el input

```
                if (text == ref_medicamento)
                {
                    var id = <?php echo json_encode($producto->id); ?>;
                    var sptext = text.split();
                    var newtr = '<tr class="item" data-id="' + id + '">';
                    newtr = newtr + '<td class="iProduct" >' + ref_medicamento + '</td>';
                    newtr = newtr + '<td class="iProduct" >' + nombre_medicamento + '</td>';
                    newtr = newtr + '<td class="iProduct"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="cant" name="ListaPro" /></td>';
                    newtr = newtr + '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove-item"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td></tr>';
                    $("#validar").append(ref_medicamento," ",nombre_medicamento,  '<br/>' );
                    $("#generar").click(function () {
                        var cant = $("input[name='ListaPro'] ").val();
                    })  
                }
```

aqui es donde muestro los valores de javascript, menos el valor del input q digito en interfaz

```
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModalDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header" style="background: #df0101; color: #ffffff">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h3 class="model-title"><strong>Estas Seguro?</strong></h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h4><strong>Verifica toda la información del pedido</strong>...<strong style="color: #df0101">RECUERDA</strong> que despues de enviado, <strong>NO</strong> hay posibilidad de cambiar informacion.</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Solicitar Pedido</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Hacer Cambios</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Podrías ponerle el id como una clase, así afectar todos.

Comment: No entendí la pregunta. ¿Qué estás tratando de capturar? ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Qué estás obteniendo actualmente con este código? Y ¿Qué se está imprimiendo desde el PHP? ¿Qué valor recibe `id`?

Comment: estoy tratando de capturar:  el valor que se ingresa de un input desde javascript para mostrarlo en html.

cual es el problema: no he podido lograr que me muestre en pantalla o por consola los valores que estoy ingresando en el input.

estoy obteniendo en codigo: el codigo y el nombre del medicamento, no hay problema con eso todo normal.

estoy imprimiendo desde php: lo mismo de arriba, codigo y nombre.

el valor que recibe id: el id es autoincrementable desde la base de datos.

Comment: hasta ahora sólo mostraste un string que estás construyendo agregándole código HTML. Pero, ¿Podrías mostrar las partes relevantes del HTML de tu página web donde está el input? ... Para aclarar la pregunta, deberías **[edit]**

Comment: Te sugiero editar la pregunta y el codigo para darle mas claridad a tu necesidad y asi poderte ayudar

Comment: Te sugiero editar tu pregunta, comenzando por escribir decentemente, además de aclarar tus ideas para dar una mejor explicación a tú problema

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de poner al `input` el `id` "**cant**" a secas, mejor añade una clase `cant` a éste y pon el `id` por ejemplo así:

```
"#cant" . $id // En PHP
"#cant" + id // En javascript
```

De esta forma consigues que el id sea único. Luego solo tienes que buscar el valor del input así:

```
var v = $(".cant > #cant" + id).val(); // Siendo id el elemento a capturar
```

En tu mismo código sería:

```
if (text == ref_medicamento) {
    var id = <?php echo json_encode($producto->id); ?>;
    var sptext = text.split();
    var newtr = '<tr class="item" data-id="' + id + '">';
    newtr = newtr + '<td class="iProduct" >' + ref_medicamento + '</td>';
    newtr = newtr + '<td class="iProduct" >' + nombre_medicamento + '</td>';
    newtr = newtr + '<td class="iProduct"><input type="number" class="form-control cant" id="cant' + id + '" name="ListaPro" /></td>';
    newtr = newtr + '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove-item"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td></tr>';
    $("#validar").append(ref_medicamento," ",nombre_medicamento,  '<br/>' );
    $("#generar").click(function () {
        var cant = $("#cant" + id).val();
        console.log(cant); // o alert(cant);
    })
}
```